# Show function is monotonic and if it has maximum or minimum without second derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives, monotone-functions

Hi all I have homework show function $f(x)= -x^{2}$ is monotonic and show it has maximum and or minimum and don't use second derivative for this.

Please say I do wrong or not because teacher control and give me bad grade if I don't know.. pls.

$$f'(x)=-2x$$

$$f'(x)=0$$

$$0=-2x |:(-2)$$

$$x=0$$

Now check if it's minimum or maximum guys here yesterday tell me how do it and I do like they said:

For $x=-1$ we have $f(-1)=1$

For $x=0$ we have $f(0)=0$

For $x=1$ we have $f(1)=-1$

This means from $1$ it goes down to $0$ and then goes even more down to $-1$

So this is not maximum and not minimum...?

Now check monotonic:

$f'(x) > 0$ monotonic increasing in $[-1,-\infty)$

$f'(x) < 0$ monotonic decreasing in $(0,\infty)$

Is all ok or wrong please say me..

Comment: Can you sketch the graph?  If so, you'll see that the function increases monotonically from $-\infty$ to $0$ and then decreases monotonically from $0$ to $+\infty$. This is not what you have written.

Comment: See, $f'(x) =-2x$, which has the opposite sign of $x$. Hence, $f(x)$ increasing whenever $x$ is negative, and decreasing whenever $x$ is positive. This is what should be written, and you have not written this.

Comment: Ok ty is correct that it has no maximum / minimum?

Comment: Monotonic over which set? $f(x)=-x^2$ is not monotonic over the interval $(-1,1)$, for instance.

Comment: Ok I think it's maximum

Answer (score 1):

Use of derivative:

Function is increasing on interval where $f'(x)\geq 0$ and decreasing on interval where $f'(x)\leq 0$.

You can see that derivative of your function is positive on interval $x<0$ and negative on interval $x>0$. This means that function is increasing on $(-\infty, 0)$ and decreasing on $(0,\infty)$ and it is monotonic on these two intervals. 
However, function is $\textbf{not}$ monotonic on its whole domain.

Next, function is increasing on interval left of  $x=0$ and then decreases on interval right of $x=0$. What can we conclude about that point? (without any further calculations, what does your intuition tell you)

Answer (score 1):

Since strict monotony implies injectivity, and $-x^2$ maps two different real numbers to the same value (e.g., both $-2$ and $2$ are mapped to $-4$), it follows that it is not injective, hence it cannot be strictly monotonic; since it is not constant over any interval, then it cannot be monotonic (assuming the domain is the real line).

As for extreme values, note that $x^2$ can never be negative for real $x.$ Hence, your function $-x^2$ can never be positive. Thus, it is always negative, or zero. Since $0$ is greater than any negative number, it follows that your function has *the* maximum value of $0.$ This is obviously attained when $x=0.$